# Bluetooth mouse constantly fails to reconnect after sleep

Tags: mouse, 13.10, bluetooth

It seems the bluetooth subsystem shows some bugs after the upgrade to 13.10. It was working quite happily at 13.04.

The bluetooth mouse I have, simply won't connect after the computer goes into any sort of sleep and has to be re-added each and every time. Sometimes the the entire bluetooth stack has vanished alltogether.

What changed with the bluetooth between these versions, that may cause this?

This is a fresh install of Kubuntu I'm using (bluedevil) no an upgrade, but the same hardware as 13.04 was happy on.

I have reported this as a bug 
https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/bluez/+bug/1246981

and added the link here as requested.

Comment: The same happens with Ubuntu Unity, so it is not exclusively an issue with the KDE-stack and tools.

Answer (score 6):

Don't want to resurrect an old question but I had this same issue in Arch and now in Ubuntu 14.04. I've been able to find a permanent work around on both systems. For those Googling for a solution this is what worked for me. Your mileage may vary. For Ubuntu I follow instruction from the [BluetoothSetup](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/BluetoothSetup#Ubuntu_11.04_Install_via_the_command_line) wiki page specifically the instruction for 11.04. For easy sake here are the steps I went through.

1. Make sure you unpair and disconnect your mouse completely
2. Set device in Pair mode
3. Open Terminal and run

   ```
   hcitool scan
   ```

   Make note of the Mac address of your device in the format of XX:XX:XX:XX:XX:XX
4. Next, enter:

   ```
   sudo bluez-simple-agent hci0 XX:XX:XX:XX:XX:XX
   sudo bluez-test-device trusted XX:XX:XX:XX:XX:XX yes
   sudo bluez-test-input connect XX:XX:XX:XX:XX:XX
   ```
5. After this you can restart bluetooth service, sleep the laptop, turn off and turn on the mouse to check.

The two main points are the last two lines in step 4. I believe they are what make the connect permanent. Their order is important it they just need to ran together.

Comment: `bluez-test-device` does not exist on my machine (18.04). People mention certain solutions for what seems like a similar issue, just with audio, at https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/bluez/+bug/1759628 , I have yet to try them out.

Answer (score 1):

What I am doing now is selecting the mouse on the bluetooth icon  and click on disconnect, after the bluetooth icon blinks I do connect and the mouse works again.

Comment: It seems to hae been fixed with the recent update. At least, I ran the updates this morning and rebooted and now my Mouse remains active. Can anyone confirm? I cannot find a ticket in launchpad for this bug.

Comment: My computer still continues not responding to the bluetooth mouse when it wakes up after suspend, i still need to disconnect and connect the mouse as i said before.

Comment: Correct: It simply does not occur always. But I confirm that it does still happen.

Comment: Unfortunately this has no effect on my Kubuntu install. Still not working.

Comment: That is a solution, true.  But not a very efficient one.

Answer (score 1):

The Bluetooth Manager utility seems to do a better job of pairing with the mouse. I believe that, as you can see in Atalaia's answer, the step of trusting the device is important, and the built in bluetooth tools don't always do that correctly.

Install the `blueman` package, run the "Bluetooth Manager" application, completely remove the mouse, pair it again, and mark it as trusted. You should only have to do this once.

Answer (score 0):

A BIOS update to the F.21 version on my HP 14dq1xx laptop corrected my problem. I assume it contained a firmware update to the Realtek RTL8821ce wireless/Bluetooth chip.